# How to insert powershell command inside cmake expression

Tags: powershell, cmake

I am creating a draw function that uses imgui API to show graphics. This function is compiled as a DLL and dynamically loaded at runtime each time it is recompiled. It works well in release mode but I want to be able to debug it. In debug a .pdb file is created and locked by the debugger such as when running my program in the debugger, the linker is unable to overwrite the previous PDB file and the library is not created

The idea is simple: for each compilation generate a new `.pdb` file with the name based on the timestamp.

The PowerShell command I use to give the timestamp is `get-date -uformat %H%M%S`.
The linker argument to set the PDB file name is `/PDB:`

I want CMake to add the following option to the linker flag: `/PDB:file_name_$(get-date -uformat %H%M%S).pdb`.

And this is where it gets tricky: CMake always interprets the `$()` and in the result, the whole expression is replaced by nothing because what is inside my `$()` has no meaning for CMake.

How can I instruct CMake to output the "$" the "(" and the ")" as characters and not interpret it?

The best I have done so far is to create a variable for those characters. It works well when putting the result in a variable but the string is always interpreted inside `add_link_options`:

```
    set(DOLLAR_LITERAL "$")
    set(OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET_LITERAL "(")
    set(CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET_LITERAL ")")
    set(TIMESTAMP_PDB "/PDB:hot_reload_draw_${DOLLAR_LITERAL}${OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET_LITERAL} 
    get-date -uformat %H%M%S${CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET_LITERAL}.pdb")
    message(${TIMESTAMP_PDB})
    target_link_options(hot_reload_draw PRIVATE ${TIMESTAMP_PDB})
```

when configuring I have the write output displayed :

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- BIOS file already downloaded
/PDB:hot_reload_draw_$( get-date -uformat %H%M%S).pdb
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Adrien COURNAND/Documents/Informatique/C++/E5150/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

and if I echo the message it gives the right output:

```
echo /PDB:hot_reload_draw_$( get-date -uformat %H%M%S).pdb
/PDB:hot_reload_draw_135735.pdb
```

But at compilation the value inside `$()` is discarded :

```
/PDB:"hot_reload_draw_.pdb"
```

I want it to be `"/PDB:hot_reload_draw_$(get-date -uformat %H%M%S).pdb"` so it is interpreted by the PowerShell

---

edit

following what @Milan said, I tried to use `[=[...]=]` quoting and switched to Ninja generator, and it looks like opened the door of weirdness...

First of all to use Ninja as build system I have to call cmake from an x64 Developper Cmd Prompt.

I edited my `CMakeLists.txt` to be `target_link_options(hot_reload_draw PRIVATE [=[/PDB:gui\hot_reload_draw_$(get-date -uformat %H%M%S).pdb]=])`, and with this `CMakeLists.txt` I have different linker arguments depending of the generator (but still not the one I want) :

- `/PDB:"gui\hot_reload_draw_.pdb"` with `"Visual Studio 17 2022"` generator (maybe visual studio generator spawn cmd process and thus the `$()` is well outputted to the script file but interpreted as empty by the cmd interpreter)
- `"/PDB:gui\hot_reload_draw_$$(get-date -uformat %H%M%S).pdb"` with Ninja as the generator almost what I want but for some reason, the "$" symbol is doubled
- ``

Comment: Check the bin/debug folder with file explorer.  Are there any files containing VHOST?  These are locks on a Network.  Try deleting (or renaming).  Does this solve issue.

Comment: So you're doing this because you want to be able to build a modified version of your program while the previous version of the program is still running? If so, how is that useful? If you want to A/B compare them at the same time, why not generate a new buildsystem for the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted but I had to trigger a configuration path each time I want a rebuild.

I edited the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if(HOT_RELOAD_PDB_NAME)
    message(INFO "Build with PDB name ${HOT_RELOAD_PDB_NAME}")
    set_property(TARGET hot_reload_draw PROPERTY PDB_NAME ${HOT_RELOAD_PDB_NAME})
endif()
```

And then I created a script that computes the value of `HOT_RELOAD_PDB_NAME` and then trigger a new CMake configuration+build path for my library :

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

cmake -B %1 -DHOT_RELOAD_PDB_NAME="hot_reload_draw_%timestamp%"
cmake --build %1 --target hot_reload_draw --verbose
```

When I want a rebuild I simply call it and it does the job.
When I issue a `dir` of binary dir I get :

```
13/01/2023  18:11         2 134 016 hot_reload_draw_181137.pdb
13/01/2023  18:36         3 274 752 hot_reload_draw_182811.pdb
13/01/2023  18:42         2 732 032 hot_reload_draw_183735.pdb
13/01/2023  18:42         2 134 016 hot_reload_draw_184237.pdb
13/01/2023  18:43         2 134 016 hot_reload_draw_184321.pdb
13/01/2023  18:49         2 134 016 hot_reload_draw_184953.pdb
13/01/2023  18:50         2 134 016 hot_reload_draw_185003.pdb
```

and it is compatible with PowerShell or Cmd.

Comment: If you are going to run `cmake` every single time and you are fine with it, then a much cleaner solution is to use `execute_process()`. Edit: Just be sure to strip it of trailing whitespaces using `OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [bracket arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-argument). I assume it is what you are looking for. I.e. you want to enclose your argument in `[=[ ]=]` - it should skip the evaluation.

EDIT: Here is a minimal example

```
set(FOO "BAR")
message(STATUS ${FOO})
message(STATUS [=[${FOO}]=])
```

This should output:

```
BAR
${FOO}
```

Comment: I didn't know that, unfortunately, it works with `${}` but not with `$()`  with `target_link_options(hot_reload_draw PRIVATE [=[/PDB:hot_reload_draw_${get-date -uformat %H%M%S}.pdb]=])` the output is still `/PDB:"hot_reload_draw_.pdb"`

Comment: There is a chance it's invoking the command from a different shell. CMake does spawn a process to which it passes arguments / commands. In this case it's apparent it gets invoked by the shell, however the input is non-existing.

Comment: One of the commenters mentioned using `execute_process` and even though it is possible to use it for your issue it has one big drawback which is the fact that you'll have to regenerate the CMake build files. Which can be a slow process. I will look into this more and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @Adrien I just realized - are you using makefiles or ninja as the main build system? If you use makefiles then the child process (shell) is usually CMD-prompt. Maybe that's the reason. With ninja it uses PS under the hood.

Comment: I am launching manually from a PowerShell with `cmake --build cmake-build-debug --target hot_reload_draw --verbose`, for the generator, I specify manually `-G "Visual Studio 17 2022"`, I had an issue when letting CMake use ninja by default (unrelated to the problem)

Comment: Yep I tried the `execute_process` it didn't but I didn't push the investigation further because as you said I have to regenerate

Comment: @Adrien The thing is, that the `blank` suffix is from `powershell` meaning I can guarantee that the statement enclosed with `[=[ ]=]` is not evaluated by CMake. I currently think you can try a workaround, by creating a `.ps` script that runs the `build` for you (not the cmake generation). You can then instead of passing `$(get-date ...)` pass `$Env:MyVariable` and in the `.ps` script you can set the environment variable i.e. `$Env:MyVariable=$(get-date ...)` and then invoke the build command. Maybe it will work that way.